# network traffic monitor in Debian?

Tags: debian, networking

I am using Debian wheezy. I am using a limited connection for Internet with 2.5 GB data limit. So I shouldn't use Internet beyond that limit. are there any available data monitors which can do me such functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `vnstatd`. It is a daemon that runs in the background and periodically polls your network interface and records the amount of data transmitted or received . This is stored in a database. The `vnstat` command lets you view bandwidth consumption broken down by day or month (very useful if your bandwidth allotment is monthly).

Debian has a [vnstat](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/vnstat) package which I believe contains `vnstatd`.

sample:
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Debian, so I couldn't tell you how to start it at boot, unless you are using `systemd` instead of the default init system.

Comment: its a deamon right ? I think its a autostart